# no errors in log still local notification flutter not working

Tags: flutter, dart, local, notify

Actually I am going to be notified when by a certain time reached, I have the following code set-up but it's not working this is my main method configuration, please tell me if there is any mistake.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
      AndroidInitializationSettings('logo');

  var initializationSettings =
      const InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
    initializationSettings,
    onSelectNotification: ((payload) async {
      if (payload != null) {
        debugPrint('notification payload: $payload');
      }
    }),
  );
  initializeTimeZones();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

And this is my method to show up local notificaion. I once used the commented code but both are not working.

```
void setNamazReminder() async {
    var schedualedNotificationDateTime = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(
      const Duration(seconds: 10),
    );
    // DateTime.now().add(
    //   const Duration(seconds: 10),
    // )
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = const AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'Prayer_notifi',
      'Go_to_Mosque',
      icon: 'logo',
      sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('_sound'),
      largeIcon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('logo'),
    );
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    );
    // await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
    //     0,
    //     'Prayer',
    //     'Time to pray now',
    //     schedualedNotificationDateTime,
    //     platformChannelSpecifics,
    //     uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
    //         UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    //     androidAllowWhileIdle: true);
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
        0,
        'Prayer',
        'Time to pray now',
        schedualedNotificationDateTime,
        platformChannelSpecifics,
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true);
  }
```